# Changing input value depending on which <a> has been clicked

Tags: javascript, dom-events

What I want to do is change the value of the input field depending on which `<a>` has been clicked by the user.

I've looked on this site and I have only found jQuery versions, but I require it to be in Vanilla JS and not using a library.

Here is the link;

http://jsbin.com/avumel/edit#javascript,html

Comment: Could you also explain what you have done if you come up with an answer please? I'm a newbie .... Appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through childNodes, if you want to do it that way: http://jsbin.com/avumel/4/edit#source

But it'd be better to append event handler to #comments and then listen the children: http://jsbin.com/avumel/8/edit

Comment: If possible, could you explain how e.target is equal to the children of #comments?

Comment: event.target (event.sourceElement in older IE's) is the source element of the event. Therefore clicking the child element returns itself. "this" will of course refer to the #comments, so it can't be used.